# How to edit the .bst file for adding comma after journal number

Tags: bibtex

The following style I want to make Latex. I am using elsevier numeric style(elsearticle-num.bst) in latex. This is journal article

R. M. Damle, P. M. Ardhapurkar, M. D. Atrey, Numerical investigation of transient behaviour of the recuperative heat exchanger in a MRJT cryocooler using different heat transfer correlations, Cryogenics, **80** (2016), pp. 52-62.

The bold number is journal volume number but no comma after it.

```
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
  {
     %%volume field.or.null
    ", "   %% This i added to get comma after Cryogenics i.e, volume name. 
    volume empty$
        { pop$ "" }
        { volume * "," *} %% This puts comma after volume number
        if$

        number empty$
            'skip$
            {   
            "~(" number * ")" * *
             volume empty$
            { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
            'skip$
            if$
            }

        if$
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your write-up is somewhat confusing. E.g., you state that you use "elsevier numeric style", which I interpret to mean that you employ the `elsarticle-num` bibliography style. Is this correct? If it is, why did you set the tag `abbrvnat.bst`? (Aside: `abbrvnat` can produce both numeric and authoryear-style citation call-outs.) Also, it's not clear what the connection is between LaTeX and (Microsoft?) word. Are you looking for help with MS Word or with LaTeX/BibTeX? Please advise.

Comment: Thanks for response, abbrvnat.bst this was added due to SE asked 5 tags, sorry for the confusion created. elsarticle-num is the .bst file i am using in latex, elsarticle-num(numeric, title) as citation style in zotero for word. I think they are same & both produce same result. It a template i want to create for the conference.

Comment: If your main question is about how to get something done under Zotero for an MS Word document, it is off-topic for this site.

Comment: i am able to style in visual csl editor, its easy to understand.  where as .bst syntax is difficult. can you please tell me how this code works. pasted above in question. I have created my own .bst with makebst, but the user want to use elsearticle-num.bst

Comment: Your write-up still isn't all that clear, forcing readers to engage in (quite likely inaccurate and hence unproductive) guesswork. For instance, the code you've posted contains no directives to render either the volume number or the string "vol." in **bold**. Moreover, the code contains no directives to output the string "vol." -- bold or not. Thus, I don't know how to interpret the look of the supposed output, which would appear to render both items in bold.

Comment: Hi the problem solved for me. i added how i did it in code. do i need to delete this question? Thanks for kind response.

Comment: You could just as well add an answer below. But remember, you are in most cases not allowed to change the file as is, but rather a copy with a different name and a comment inside what you changed and when.

Comment: Luckily i added comments inside file where i made changes to remember. Is it illegal to modify the original files and keep them in same name? For now I have changed file name with title inside so users can see its modified.